# Is the method of change of coordinates similar in any way to factorization of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, algebraic-curves

I'm reading a book on plane algebraic curves. It's a brazilian portuguese book, so I guess the title would be uninteresting to others, but if you want to know the title, just tell me $\tiny \text{and we can trade for some nudes.}$

At analytic geometry classes, I learned that conics can be represented in an equation such as:

$$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0\tag{1}$$

And then we use the method of change of coordinates to simplify it and check if they are of one of the following forms:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} \pm \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \quad \quad  \quad \quad y^2=4ax\tag{2}$$

At the book I mentioned earlier, it is said that each of these polynomial equations is in irreducible form. From the faint knowledge I have from algebra, an irreducible polynomial is a non-constant polynomial that can't be factored in a product of two non-constant polynomials. Is there an analogy between these two notions? That is: Is change of coordinates to obtain $(2)$, in some way, analog to factoring $(1)$?

I am aware that the curve in $(1)$ is not really *the same* as the curves given in $(2)$, they are *the same* by means of isometry. But I'm curious if change of coordinates is in any meaningful way similar to the factorization of polynomials.

Comment: I think the book is using "irreducible" to mean, "can't be further simplified". I suppose irreducible polynomials can't be simplified, either, if you consider factorization to be simplification, but I think that's as far as the analogy goes.

Comment: So, what do you reckon?

Comment: Until now, I didn't proceed much further. I thought that there could be an analogy between these notions,  but I guess I don't have enough knowledge to find out myself.